# Fitness proportionate selection (roulette wheel selection) in Python

Tags: python, random, genetic-algorithm

I have a list of objects (Chromosome) which have an attribute fitness (chromosome.fitness is between 0 and 1)

Given a list of such objects, how can I implement a function which returns a single chromosome whose chance of being selected is proportional to its fitness? That is, a chromosome with fitness 0.8 is twice as likely to be selected as one with fitness 0.4.

I've found a few Python and pseudocode implementations, but they are too complex for this requirement: the function needs only a list of chromosomes. Chromosomes store their own fitness as an internal variable.

The implementation I already wrote was before I decided to allow chromosomes to store their own fitness, so was a lot more complicated and involved zipping lists and things.

### ----------------------------EDIT----------------------------

Thanks Lattyware. The following function seems to work.

```
def selectOne(self, population):
    max     = sum([c.fitness for c in population])
    pick    = random.uniform(0, max)
    current = 0
    for chromosome in population:
        current += chromosome.fitness
        if current > pick:
            return chromosome
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `numpy.random.choice`:

```
import numpy.random as npr
def selectOne(self, population):
    max = sum([c.fitness for c in population])
    selection_probs = [c.fitness/max for c in population]
    return population[npr.choice(len(population), p=selection_probs)]
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer: simple and most likely faster then all other options

Comment: I tested (please, replace **#** with `\n`, and **&** with `\t`):
`v1 = {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0} #
v2 = v1.copy() #
for i in range(100000): #
&    v1[next(c for c, b in zip(range(4), np.cumsum([0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25])) if np.random.rand() < b)] += 1 #
&    v2[np.random.choice([0,1,2,3],p=[0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25])] += 1 #
print(v1,'\n',v2)`
Resulting in: v1 = {0: 25028, 1: *37618*, 2: 27952, 3: *9402*} and v2 = {0: 24911, 1: 25064, 2: 24853, 3: 25172}. **numpy choice** behaves as expected; @PyDeq answer's with next-zip-if does not...

Comment: It should be noted that all of these answers that assign values to the variable`max` are overwriting the reference to the built-in function `max`, which may lead to errors such as `TypeError: 'float' object is not callable`.

Answer (score 16):

There is a very simple way to select a weighted random choice from a dictionary:

```
def weighted_random_choice(choices):
    max = sum(choices.values())
    pick = random.uniform(0, max)
    current = 0
    for key, value in choices.items():
        current += value
        if current > pick:
            return key
```

If you don't have a dictionary at hand, you could modify this to suit your class (as you haven't given more details of it, or generate a dictionary:

```
choices = {chromosome: chromosome.fitness for chromosome in chromosomes}
```

Presuming that fitness is an attribute.

Here is an example of the function modified to take an iterable of chromosomes, again, making the same presumption.

```
def weighted_random_choice(chromosomes):
    max = sum(chromosome.fitness for chromosome in chromosomes)
    pick = random.uniform(0, max)
    current = 0
    for chromosome in chromosomes:
        current += chromosome.fitness
        if current > pick:
            return chromosome
```

Comment: If you have many choices, or you have to pick many values with the same set of weights, you could also turn this O(n) solution into a O(log(n)) solution by using a binary search, or even an O(1) solution by using some kind of look-up table.

Comment: @SvenMarnach This is true, I'm giving the simplest solution here, not necessarily the fastest - that is indeed worth noting.

Comment: [This article](http://www.keithschwarz.com/darts-dice-coins/) gives a nice exposition of developing an O(1) algorithm for this sampling.

Comment: Do you know why, if this function is called twice in succession, it always returns the same chromosome?

Comment: @Blazemore That should not happen. It would imply either your list is of length 1, or for some reason the seed for the ``random`` module isn't changing. Some quick tests on my side show that it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer fewer lines:

```
import itertools

def choose(population):
    bounds = list(itertools.accumulate(chromosome.fitness for chromosome in population))
    pick = random.random() * bounds[-1]
    return next(chromosome for chromosome, bound in zip(population, bounds) if pick < bound)
```

Comment: Please, refer to my comment to @cw' answer... Your proposal does not behave as expected.

Comment: @iperetta, there was a mistake in your benchmark. As for the next-zip-if line, you need to call `np.random.rand` outside of the list comprehension. The fixed benchmark would look like this: https://trinket.io/python3/f8cd831209

Answer (score 2):

```
def Indvs_wieght(Indvs): # to comput probality of selecting each Indvs by its fitness
    s=1
    s=sum(i.fitness for i in Indvs)
    wieghts = list()
    for i in range(len(Indvs)) :
        wieghts.append(Indvs[i].fitness/s)
    return wieghts  

def select_parents(indvs,indvs_wieghts,number_of_parents=40): # Roulette Wheel Selection method  #number of selected  parent 
    return np.random.choice(indvs,size=number_of_parents,p=indvs_wieghts)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import random,pdb
import operator

def roulette_selection(weights):
        '''performs weighted selection or roulette wheel selection on a list
        and returns the index selected from the list'''

        # sort the weights in ascending order
        sorted_indexed_weights = sorted(enumerate(weights), key=operator.itemgetter(1));
        indices, sorted_weights = zip(*sorted_indexed_weights);
        # calculate the cumulative probability
        tot_sum=sum(sorted_weights)
        prob = [x/tot_sum for x in sorted_weights]
        cum_prob=np.cumsum(prob)
        # select a random a number in the range [0,1]
        random_num=random.random()

        for index_value, cum_prob_value in zip(indices,cum_prob):
            if random_num < cum_prob_value:
                return index_value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    weights=[1,2,6,4,3,7,20]
    print (roulette_selection(weights))
    weights=[1,2,2,2,2,2,2]
    print (roulette_selection(weights))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import random

def weighted_choice(items):
    total_weight = sum(item.weight for item in items)
    weight_to_target = random.uniform(0, total_weight)
    for item in items:
        weight_to_target -= item.weight
        if weight_to_target <= 0:
            return item
```