# Is there a way to retrieve a python object from one of its attributes? (Python)

Tags: python, discord

I am a beginner making a discord bot, and for one command, I have objects and their chances to be encountered, using this format:

```
chances = 5, 5
objects = array[0].name, array[1].name
location = [v for v, d in zip(objects, chances) for i in range(d)]
for i in range(1):
    print(random.choice(location))
```

I want to save the object as a variable to be used in another command, particularly to access another attribute for information. But, since objects uses one of its attributes, and not the object itself, I was wondering if in python it was possible to retrieve the object from one of its attributes, in my case the name, where no object has the same name. I am also very open to alternative solutions, being a beginner, I am sure there are other solutions that might be more efficient

Answer (score 1):

I don't belie this is possible. however you could create a dictionary that references the objects by there name. like this

```
chances = 5, 5
objects = array[0].name, array[1].name
object_name_to_object = {}
for val in array:
     object_name_to_object[val.name] = val
location = [v for v, d in zip(objects, chances) for i in range(d)]
for i in range(1):
     objct= object_name_to_object[random.choice(location)]
print(objct)
```

or just not use the name at all like this:

```
chances = 5, 5
objects = array[0], array[1]
location = [v for v, d in zip(objects, chances) for i in range(d)]
for i in range(1):
      print(random.choice(location))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use **roulette wheel selection** for this task. There is a simple implementation here [Fitness proportionate selection (roulette wheel selection) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324015/fitness-proportionate-selection-roulette-wheel-selection-in-python)