# Random changing weight

Tags: python, random

I need to implement a class where I am able generate random element based on their weight. The tricky part is that I also need to be able to change the weight.

Here is an example output

```
set_weight("A", 4.0)
set_weight("B", 6.0)
get_random() # return "A" 40% probability, "B" 60%
set_weight("A", 3.0)
get_random() # return "A" 33% probability, "B" 66%
```

My approach to solving is to find the prefix sum every time a weight is added and append the (element, current_sum_weight) tuple into the list. For set_weight("A", 4.0) and set_weight("B", 6.0), the array would be [("A", 4.0), ("B", 10.0)] Then I generate a random number between 0 and the current sum then iterate through the array to find the first sum weight that is less than the random number and return that element.

However, I don't know how to update the sum weight, because then I would have to iterate through the array and then find the element and update all the weight of elements after. What is a way that I can implement an update for the weight?

I don't know if using dictionary is better, or maybe I should use an ordered dictionary.

Comment: `random.choices`?

Comment: I'm supposed to write my own class and I don't think I am supposed to use the built-in function

Comment: How do you want to generate random number without build-in function then?

Comment: I can use the random module for a random number, but I cannot use the function choices, because it is supposed to be a OOP problem that I have to write a randomGenerator class and build the weight functionality

Comment: choose: keep cumulative soom, use bisect_left to find insertion position - that'll reduce search time from linear to log. IMO Weight update: there is no way around linear complexity here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324015/fitness-proportionate-selection-roulette-wheel-selection-in-python  this may help you.  it is a roulette wheel selection problem

Answer (score -1):

```py
class Random_gen:

    def __init__(self):
        self.elements = {}
        

    def set_weight(self, element, weight):
        self.elements[element] = weight

    def get_random(self):
        total_weight = sum(self.elements.values())
        rnd = random.randint(0, total_weight)
        added_weight = 0
        for element, weight in self.elements.items():
            added_weight += weight
            if rnd < added_weight:
                return element
```